# Tibco send command

Tags: tibco, tibco-rv

I'm trying to send message using tibrvsend command.

The scenarios is like below ,

I've server running on network , I'm able to ping the server Ip address and able to connect using remote desktop connection.

On the server i'm listening to the subject

```
tibrvlisten -service 7541 -network ;239.193.1.110 MY.SUBJECT
```

From my local machine I'm trying to send message to the same subject above, but it is not reaching to the server. If i use the same send command on the server it is working fine and message is reaching . I'm not able send the same from my local to server.

```
tibrvsend -service 7541 -network 184.10.34.9;239.193.1.110 -daemon tcp:7541  MY.SUBJECT "Hello Test Message"
```

The error i'm getting on console is `tibrvsend: Failed to initialize transport: Could not resolve network specification`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep the network parameter as simple as possible, and only use the daemon parameter if you are running multiple daemons or using a remote daemon.

```
tibrvsend -service 7541 -network ";239.193.1.110"  MY.SUBJECT "Hello Test Message"
```

On Windows you often have multiple network adapters which is why you sometimes need to be more specific with the first parameter.   The interface address is usually the easiest form to use as you have discovered.

```
-network "<local ip address>;239.193.1.110" ...
```

On Unix platforms you can use the interface name or network name from `/etc/networks` but you do not have this luxury on Windows, and often IPv6 renders it unusable.

Read the RV Concepts Guide for more discussion on the network parameter.

```
-network "<hostname>;239.193.1.110" ...
```

The most useful being network IP, e.g. 1.2.3. will match interface 1.2.3.4

```
-network "<network IP>;239.193.1.110" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working..

tibrvsend -service 7541 -network "local-ip;239.193.1.110;server-ip" MY.SUBJECT "This is from local machine"

Comment: That network parameter is still wrong, you have it configured with asymmetric multicast.  Drop the "server-ip".